# Drawing rectangle with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw three small rectangles 0.3*0.3 cm at the positions (11.1,5.5) resp. (11.1,5) and (11.1,4.5). I have tried do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [draw=black] (11.1,5.5) rectangle (0.3,0.3);
\filldraw [fill=Peach, draw=black] (11.1,5) rectangle (0.3,0.3);
\filldraw [fill=RedOrange, draw=black] (11.1,4.5) rectangle (0.3,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the result is rectangles that are 11.1*5 cm in size. How do I change to get the right size?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 77):

The `rectangle` command requires the absolute corner coordinates. You are giving the increments in the second coordinates.

For that you need to write:

```
\draw[draw=black] (11.1,5.5) rectangle ++(0.3,0.3);
```